# How to give 2 different colours of the font to the vertical text, in order to text 1 and text 2 was in one "div class"?

Tags: html, css

Two texts are saved on the "background-color: blue" for the test.
I have two "div class":

1) vertical-text1 (text color ---> white)

2) vertical-text2 (text color ---> yellow + font-weight: bold)

My code:

```
<div class="video_info">
    <div class="vertical-text1">text 1</div>
    <div class="vertical-text2">text 2</div>
</div>


.video_info
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 30px;
    top: 70%;
}

.vertical-text1
{
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    color: white;
    background-color: #0000ff;
    position: absolute;
    left: -190px;
    top: -215px;
    width: 400px;
}

.vertical-text2
{
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #0000ff;
    position: absolute;
    left: -40px;
    top: -350px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

How to give 2 different colours of the font to the vertical text, in order to text 1 and text 2 was in one "div class"?

Comment: it's not very clear what you are asking.. do you want different text colors for 'text 1' and 'text 2' but without setting them in any html element separately?

Comment: Yes, only in one div "vertical-text1". Two divs "vertical-text1" and "vertical-text2" to stake out a place more in CSS and styles are repeating.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have two elements with different styling without making them different somehow. What you can do is move your common styling inside a class and leave the individual styling as it is, separate for each element (using IDs), so there is no duplicate code.

```
<div class="video_info">
    <span id="vertical-text1" class="vertical-text">text 1</span>
    <span id="vertical-text2" class="vertical-text">text 2</span>
</div>

.video_info
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 30px;
    top: 70%;
}

.vertical-text {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    background-color: #0000ff;
    position: absolute;
}

#vertical-text1
{
    color: white;
    left: -190px;
    top: -215px;
    width: 400px;
}

#vertical-text2
{
    color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: -40px;
    top: -350px;
    width: 100px;
}
```